# How to retrieve a particular record and display its details in listview Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a table named userinfo which has columns rollno,name,fullname,fathername etc....
I want to retrieve a particular rollno and display his details in a `listview`. I am using Android studio for coding.

```
public class TrainingActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String jsonResult;
    public String url ="";
    ListView listView;
    List<Map<String,String>> activity = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_training);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        accessWebService();
    }

    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try{
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
            String rLine ="";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try{
                while((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null){
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error ..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return  answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            ListDrwaer(); // we will create it later
        }
    }

    public void accessWebService(){
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[] {url});
    }

    public void ListDrwaer (){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResonse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.substring(jsonResult.indexOf("{"), jsonResult.lastIndexOf("}")+1));
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResonse.optJSONArray("name");

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            HashMap<String,String> map;

            for(int i=0; i<jsonMainNode.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String,String>();

                map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
                map.put("email", c.getString("email"));


                MyArrList.add(map);

                SimpleAdapter sAdap;
                sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(TrainingActivity.this, MyArrList, R.layout.activity_column, new String[]{"name","email"}, new int[]{R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName});

                listView.setAdapter(sAdap);
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error ..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet ??? first research the same properly and if you find any issues in your code then post it here with the error msg

Answer (score 0):

Make a Rest API with post method and use parameter rollno. In android when use this api set a particular rollno. In this way you will get all records of particular rollno. For Http request use loopj library and for parsing use gson library. Both are best for web API.

Comment: can you suggest me any links so that i can understand. I have written php code for the search, am unable to write the java code in android studio and use that url.Any help please..